# How to pass SEDOL identifications in one column to second column in order to find ticker and other information

Tags: excel, bloomberg

In one column I have the SEDOL identification of companies and in other columns I want to access the ticker, EPS, Revenues, etc. of that company. How do I pass the contents of a cell in the SEDOl column into a formula in another column?

I know the function I should be using is

`=BDP("/SEDOL1/####### Equity", "TICKER")`

and it works when I manually input each SEDOL number into the pound signs, but when I try

`=BDP("/SEDOL1/A2 Equity", "TICKER")`

or other variations with parenthesis etc. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
=BDP(A2 & " SEDOL", "TICKER")
```

Symbology in Excel is as follows:

```
<Name>[Exchange][Coupon][Maturity]<Yellow Key>[Type]
```

For example:

```
594918104 Equity Cusip
```